# How to take 2 characters of a string and remove everything until the next string using sed

Tags: linux, sed

I am trying to take the first 2 characters of the first word which would be "wo" and remove everything else and combine it with the second word.

**Example:**

```
worker1, 0001, company1
worker2, 0002, company2
worker3, 0003, company3
worker4, 0004, company4
worker5, 0005, company5
```

**I want the following output:**

```
wo0001, company1
wo0002, company2
wo0003, company3
wo0004, company4
wo0005, company5
```

So far I have used the following command: sed -e `'s/\(r\).*\(,\)/\2/' workers.txt` and it took the first 2 characters but it delete the second word that it was suppose to combine with.

```
wo, company1
wo, company2
wo, company3
wo, company4
wo, company5
```

Can anybody tell me where I went wrong and point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: I would use `awk` instead